# Why there is public in variables declartions?

Tags: java

It isn't by default like that?
For example:

```
**public** int [name];
**public** String [name];
```

Comment: By default variables are package-private.

Answer (score 4):

By default it's package-private access (allowing any class belonging to the same package to access it), not public.

Anyway, it's bad practice to define data members as public. In most cases they should be private.

Comment: You mean fields, not members. Some members need to be public, otherwise there's not much happening.

Comment: @biziclop I fixed my phrasing to "data members", as opposed to methods.